# Updating the page without update_page and rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So, with all this about using UJS and RJS being removed from rails 3.1, I am wondering how I will go about updating a relatively large amount of html on a page. Before I could just render a partial from the insert_html method, how should I do this now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascript, or any framework you like. I prefer jQuery.

```
 $("#somediv").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "/path/to/partial") %>")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, load it with jQuery's load method:

```
$('#somediv').load('/some/path');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty nifty javascript partial page loader that [@defunkt](http://github.com/defunkt) has put together.

It's called [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). It enables partial page reloading and expected functionality with the back button for browsers that support history.pushstate API

> ### what is it?
>
> pjax loads HTML from your server into
>   the current page without a full
>   reload. It's ajax with real
>   permalinks, page titles, and a working
>   back button that fully degrades.
>
> pjax enhances the browsing experience
>   - nothing more.
>
> You can find a demo at
>   http://pjax.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

UJS,  RJS, templates and helpers will still be supported via optional gems.